# Error building custom Docker image with Postgres and security updates: "configuration file createcluster.conf is available"

Tags: postgresql, docker

I have a Dockerfile that builds an image based on `postgres`, but additionally installs security updates (this is to ensure that the image has the latest patches even if a release is slightly older).

This is the Dockerfile:

```
FROM postgres:14.2

# apply security updates
RUN \
  apt-get update -qq && \
  apt-get upgrade -y && \
  rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*

ENV PGDATA /var/lib/postgresql/data

# switch to lower-privileged user
USER 999

CMD ["postgres", "-c", "listen_addresses=*", "-c", "config_file=/etc/postgresql/postgresql.conf"]
```

Now, this build broke:

```
Reading package lists...
Building dependency tree...
Reading state information...
Calculating upgrade...
The following packages will be upgraded:
  libpq5 postgresql-14 postgresql-client-14 postgresql-client-common
  postgresql-common
5 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
Need to get 17.9 MB of archives.
After this operation, 25.6 kB of additional disk space will be used.
Get:1 http://apt.postgresql.org/pub/repos/apt bullseye-pgdg/main amd64 libpq5 amd64 14.3-1.pgdg110+1 [172 kB]
Get:2 http://apt.postgresql.org/pub/repos/apt bullseye-pgdg/main amd64 postgresql-common all 241.pgdg110+1 [230 kB]
Get:3 http://apt.postgresql.org/pub/repos/apt bullseye-pgdg/main amd64 postgresql-client-common all 241.pgdg110+1 [92.1 kB]
Get:4 http://apt.postgresql.org/pub/repos/apt bullseye-pgdg/main amd64 postgresql-client-14 amd64 14.3-1.pgdg110+1 [1,629 kB]
Get:5 http://apt.postgresql.org/pub/repos/apt bullseye-pgdg/main amd64 postgresql-14 amd64 14.3-1.pgdg110+1 [15.8 MB]
debconf: delaying package configuration, since apt-utils is not installed
Fetched 17.9 MB in 1s (25.4 MB/s)
(Reading database ... 12100 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../libpq5_14.3-1.pgdg110+1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libpq5:amd64 (14.3-1.pgdg110+1) over (14.2-1.pgdg110+1) ...
Preparing to unpack .../postgresql-common_241.pgdg110+1_all.deb ...
Leaving 'diversion of /usr/bin/pg_config to /usr/bin/pg_config.libpq-dev by postgresql-common'
Unpacking postgresql-common (241.pgdg110+1) over (238.pgdg110+1) ...
Preparing to unpack .../postgresql-client-common_241.pgdg110+1_all.deb ...
Unpacking postgresql-client-common (241.pgdg110+1) over (238.pgdg110+1) ...
Preparing to unpack .../postgresql-client-14_14.3-1.pgdg110+1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking postgresql-client-14 (14.3-1.pgdg110+1) over (14.2-1.pgdg110+1) ...
Preparing to unpack .../postgresql-14_14.3-1.pgdg110+1_amd64.deb ...
invoke-rc.d: could not determine current runlevel
invoke-rc.d: policy-rc.d denied execution of stop.
Unpacking postgresql-14 (14.3-1.pgdg110+1) over (14.2-1.pgdg110+1) ...
Setting up postgresql-client-common (241.pgdg110+1) ...
Setting up libpq5:amd64 (14.3-1.pgdg110+1) ...
Setting up postgresql-client-14 (14.3-1.pgdg110+1) ...
Setting up postgresql-common (241.pgdg110+1) ...
debconf: unable to initialize frontend: Dialog
debconf: (TERM is not set, so the dialog frontend is not usable.)
debconf: falling back to frontend: Readline
Configuring postgresql-common
-----------------------------
createcluster.conf: A new version (/tmp/postgresql-common.sK2jGD) of
configuration file /etc/postgresql-common/createcluster.conf is available, but
the version installed currently has been locally modified.
  1. install the package maintainer's version
  2. keep the local version currently installed
  3. show the differences between the versions
  4. show a side-by-side difference between the versions
  5. start a new shell to examine the situation
What do you want to do about modified configuration file createcluster.conf?
```

How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The build breaks because it asks you what to do, and from a script (or automated build), this is not possible.

The solution is to allow `apt` to configure the installation noninteractively. Add to your Dockerfile:

```
ENV DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive
```

This way, automatic selections to the packages will apply. This is fine for most cases.